# Convert remove navigationBar border to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

i'm trying to remove the navigationBar border in swift. This is done by using following code in objective-c:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

How can this be done in swift?

i've tried this, but not working:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: nope no error message

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Answer (score 8):

To change the background, text and icons colors, and also remove the border/shadow of the navigation bar via the appearance proxy, insert this code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of `AppDelegate`:

```
// our colors
let backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
let foregroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// status bar text color (.LightContent = white, .Default = black)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
// solid or translucent background?
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
// remove bottom shadow
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
// background color
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(backgroundColor.toImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
// controls and icons color
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = foregroundColor
// text color
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: foregroundColor]
```

**Note:** As you can see, we need to convert the `UIColor` to `UIImage`, so you can use this extension:

```
extension UIColor{
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0)
        self.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Use it like this: `UIColor.redColor().toImage()`

Answer (score 5):

I have used the below code to remove the navigation bar shadow from the app.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Yeah, works if you're not afraid of loosing the background color to the status bar

Comment: It works fine, this is the right answer, and i have a custom color of the status bar, and didn't loose it. At least this works with a custom navigation bar. I Don't use navigationController?.navigationBar, but instead, i added myself a UINavigationBar to the storyboard. Because my navigation bar needs some specific customization. Thanks @Rahul Nair!