# remove black border from UISearchController search bar swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UISearchController in my tableView. Also note that there is a navigation item in the top.
My issue is that i have a black border in the top and bottom when I load the page, however, it is not present when I click the search bar.

Search bar on page load (with black border):

[image]

After clicking on search bar (no black border):

[image]

Here is the code related:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

I followed several similar questions and made the following changes after the above lines in `viewDidLoad()`:

1) `searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()`

2) `searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal`

3) `searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor`

4)

```
 searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

None worked. Is this an issue with the order I am using the code, or how would I get rid of these lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed this after a lot of search.  Here's how i did it. In `viewDidLoad`, added the following lines:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.translucent = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

After that in app.delegate file in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` added the following code:

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        let foregroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(backgroundColor.toImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = foregroundColor

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: foregroundColor]
```

Also need this extension on the app.delegate file (place outside of the class)

```
extension UIColor{
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0)
        self.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

(Thanks to Noel for the extension taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640096/4858605))

And finally, the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the navigation bar you need to remove the border for.

[How to hide iOS7 UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

Comment: Your link had this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24974907/4858605 could be potentionally useful, although I couldn't test it out.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 13 / Swift 5; the following line makes the trick:

```
  UISearchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

Cheers!